# Insert point to line

Tags: postgis

How I can insert point to LINESTRING in PostGIS? For example, I have line like `LINESTRING(0 0, 10 0)` and point which lies on line segment: `POINT(5, 0)`. I need to add this point to line. Expected result is `LINESTRING(0 0, 5 0, 10 0)`. It looks like `ST_AddPoint(geometry linestring, geometry point, integer position);` can helps me but I don't know how I can determine position value in case if line will not so simple.

Comment: `SELECT ST_AddPoint('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 0)'::geometry,'POINT(5 0)'::geometry,1)` will work. It's not clear what you mean by "when the line is not so simple," or how your solution below addresses the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've found such solution:

```
WITH geom AS
  ( SELECT 'LINESTRING(0 0, 10 0)'::geometry l,
           'POINT(5 0)'::geometry p),
     series AS
  ( SELECT generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(l)-1) n
   FROM geom)
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_AddPoint(geom.l, geom.p, series.n))
FROM geom,
     series
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_MakeLine(ST_PointN(l, n), ST_PointN(l, n+1)), geom.p);
```